# From Excel to Python: from columns to strings

Tags: python, excel, list

I have an Excel file with 2 columns (it is an CSV file). The first contains dates, while the second contains numbers.

I want to make a list out of this with Python, the following way: ['date1','number1','date2','number2']. At the moment I always get: ['date1;number1','date2;number2']. I basically want every element to be treated as a string on its own.

At the moment I'm using following code:

```
abc = []

with open('C:...doc.csv', 'r', encoding = "utf8") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f) 
    for row in reader:
        abc.extend([row])
```

I've tried everything I could come up with, e.g. nested for etc, but nothing seems to work.

Can anyone help me out please? Thank you!

Comment: `abc.extend(row.split(';'))` should work.

Comment: The problem is that your "CSV" file is delimited with ';'s. This can be quite easily fixed with `with open('C:...doc.csv', 'r', encoding = "utf8", delimiter=';') as f:`. Also, you probably want `abc.append(row)` instead of `abc.extend(row)`

Comment: I did it like this:with open('C:..doc.csv', 'r', encoding = "utf8") as f:
   reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';') 
   for row in reader:
       abc.append(row)